# Extracting n-th part of an expression without any evaluation

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, hold, head

Is it possible to extract n-th part of an expression as a string, without any evaluation?
For example,

```
In[1]   x=1;y=2;z=3;
In[2]   SomeCode[Plus[x,y,z], 2]
Out[2]  "y" (* y as a string! *)
```

I've tried

```
  In[2] Defer[Unevaluated[Plus[x,y,z]][[2]]]
```

but failed :

```
  Out[2] Unevaluated[Plus[x, y, z]][[2]] (* fail *)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `y` would not be a string if you pulled it from the example expression. Instead, you would need to somehow have it be changed to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `Extract` with `Hold` and `Unevaluated` to make it into a string, like:

```
x = 1; y = 2; z = 3;
t = Extract[Hold[Plus[x, y, z]], {1, 2}, Hold ];
t /. Hold[y_] -> ToString[Unevaluated[y]]

(* y *)
```

Comment: +1.  Similar: `Construct[ToString, Extract[Hold[Plus[x, y, z]], {1, 2}, Unevaluated]]`.  Another variation close to the OP's initial attempt: `Extract[Unevaluated[Plus[x, y, z]], 2, Defer]`.